# MongoDB Aggregation group students by their current class and get sum of students with the religion = Christian

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

I have some information about some students. From this data I want to group students by their current class and get sum of students with the religion = Christian

//data

```
[{
    "indexNumber": 11111,
    "currentClass": "3C",
    "gender": "Female",
    "religon": "Christian",
  },
{
    "indexNumber": 22222,
    "currentClass": "3E",
    "gender": "Male",
    "religon": "Hindu",
  }

 ]
```

//Aggregation group (what I have currently done)

```
const stats = await Student.aggregate([
      {
        $group: {
          _id: '$currentClass',
          totalNumStudentsInSchool: { $sum: 1 },
          christianStudents: { $sum: { $religon: 'Christian' } },
        },
      },
    ]);
```

//Error is coming when I add this line

```
christianStudents: { $sum: { $religon: 'Christian' } }
```

//I want an output like this

```
"stats": [
            {
                "_id": "3C",
                "christianStudents": 1
            },
            {
                "_id": "3E",
                "christianStudents": 0
            },
        ]
```

Comment: But 3E religon is "Hindu"...so the it looks like you should update your wanted output

Answer (score 1):

You can use $cond for such operations, see below code

```
const stats = await Student.aggregate([
      {
        $group: {
          _id: '$currentClass',
          totalNumStudentsInSchool: { $sum: 1 },
          christianStudents: {$sum: {$cond: [ {$eq: [  "$religon", "Christian" ]} , 1 , 0 ]}},
        },
      },
    ]);
```

Comment: Thank you sooo much it worked, But why we should use 1, 0 at the end. Please can you explain

Comment: It is a part of the condition where if the condition is true, then it returns 1 to $sum. Otherwise, it returns 0 to $sum.

Comment: Wow amazing, I understood that.. thanks again...

Comment: You can write it even shorter: `christianStudents: { $sum: { $toInt: { $eq: ["$religon", "Christian"] } } }`, see [$toInt Behavior](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/v4.4/reference/operator/aggregation/toInt/#behavior)